# How to iterate Hashmap of HashMap in Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, java-8

Here is the example:

```
{
"options": [
{
  "price": {
    "amount": 0
  },
  "serviceOption": {
    "activationDate": "string",
    "conflictsWith": [
      "string"
    ],
    "content": {
      "name": "string",
      "shortText": "string"
    },
    "dependsOn": "string",
    "durationPeriod": "MONTH",
    "earliestDeactivationDate": "string",
    "fee": 0,
    "feePeriod": "MONTH",
    "groupId": "string",
    "installed": true,
    "minimumDuration": 0,
    "modifiable": true,
    "productId": "string",
    "scheduledDeactivationDate": "string",
    "status": "RECURRING"
  }
}
]
}
```

Here I need to get the value of `groupId`

```
options->serviceOption->groupId
```

As per my requirements, I have above json objects and converted into Hashmap to iterate, How to iterate hashmap of hashmap using stream?

To iterate HashMap i used `hashmap.entrySet().stream()` but then what should i do to iterate further?

Question updated:

Comment: Why do you want to use stream? Since you already know path to data you want tto get why not use `yourMap.get("options")` to get (I am assuming) List and since that list contains only one object (map) pick it via `.get(0)` and then on that map `get("serviceOption")` which also holds object (map) on which you can call `get("groupId")`. In short `String groupId = yourMap.get("options").get(0).get("serviceOption").get("groupId");`.

Comment: I can understand your approach. but Im supposed to use Stream only.

Comment: "but Im supposed to use Stream only" why? Is someone threatening you?

Comment: is there possible to do this by stream?

Comment: Why stream over only ***one*** possible path (since based on what you showed us `options` array contain only one object)? This makes no sense, making your question unclear.

Comment: Your actual task is to extract a particular value from a JSON string. There are dedicated tools/libraries to do that. All your other “requirements”, like generating a `HashMap` or iterating over it via streams, are artificial. Also known as [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: My requirements is to read the given json objects and and get the respective value using stream(i tried to convert to hashmap and tried-not worked)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can iterate over `groupId`s of available options:

```
options.stream().map(option -> option.get("serviceOption").get("groupId")).forEach(groupId -> /* Do something with each groupId here */)
```

Comment: i have above jsonobjects in hashmap. above is not working anyhow

Answer (score 0):

One approach, starting from a map, is:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>(); // Your map initialization code goes here.
Stream<Entry<String, Object>> stream = map.entrySet().stream();
// put code to consume stream here.
```